# React Native DevSettingsActivity exposing in Release build

Tags: react-native

there is a problem with React Native Developer Settings Activity in our project. The problem is, the activity is exposing in release build. It should not expose. I have tried `android:exported=false` in `main/AndroidManifest`. Should I just add activity to debug manifest?

Answer (score 0):

On your end yes, you can move it to the `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` (like in the diff in the link below)

Apparently, a fix will be shipped in React Native 0.64 in the template for new apps: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/d8e6c45782a5c9132bb7ec315fe0b9ba3999e830

Comment: It should be visible when I decompiled the code and search for the DevSettingsActivity, it shows in the list. So what should I do to remove this from the decompilation for Android or can we delete debug package from Android itself?